# Is there a way to implement Ansible dynamic inventory without the access key and secret key? Like a IAM role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-iam

I want to implement Ansible with dynamic inventory but with an IAM role, is it possible?

Comment: Could you describe your specific use case?

Comment: I am guessing you did not see the [`iam_role_arn:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/inventory/aws_ec2.html#parameter-iam_role_arn) parameter? Although TBH I would bet [`aws_profile:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/inventory/aws_ec2.html#parameter-aws_profile) will be the easiest to reason about, since it captures the originating credentials and the role to assume, whereas (AFAIK) using `iam_role_arn:` still requires the rest to be populated anyway to bootstrap things

Comment: If you mean _literally_ without **any** initial access key and secret, then only `aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity` or running the dynamic inventory on an instance that has access to the IMDS is your only hope. There is no "http basic" auth, if that's what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you are using the same account where your controller node present like in ec2 instance!
you can get the temporary authorization for some services but that controller node must be of the same account.